# PHP mysql_connect vs Ubuntu mysql terminal use

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-connect

I'm using PHP in order to connect to MySQL with the following way:

```
$link = mysql_connect('...host...', '...username...', '...password...'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

and it connects just fine.
But when trying from my terminal this

```
mysql -h ...host... -u ....username... -p ...password...
```

I give my password and i take as a result this:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '...host...' (111)
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: Do you have apache installed? What does sudo status mysql output?

Comment: When you say "my terminal", do you mean a terminal on your own system or on the server (through SSH)?

Comment: @PaulPRO I use a hosting provider @Francois a terminal on my own system ...

Comment: It's quite possible that the host isn't available publicly. The hostname may point to an internal IP address or the MySQL server may only accept connections from the local network.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I was specifying the ip address of the server when I should have been writing `localhost` for the ip address. Note that I wasn't trying to connect remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo mysql -h ....etc.

I'm running linuxMint and had to use either su or sudo. I think by default you have to be root to enter the terminal. But with Ubuntu root is inaccessible, the only feature I don't like about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The php code is running on the web server, your local command is running on your machine.

MySQL accounts are not just usernames - they are username + hostname combos. So both have to match for MySQL to find the account.

Since your hostname is different from the one the web server uses MySQL does not consider it a valid user. (It's possible to set the hostname to % which means "Any".)